# Multithreading returns an unhandled exception for storing information

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception

I will try to explain my problem as clear as possible. I have a multithreading framework I have to work on. It's a path tracer renderer. It gives me error when I try to store some information provided by my threads. Trying to avoid posting all the code, I will explain what I mean step by step:

my TileTracer class is a thread

```
class TileTracer : public Thread{
...
}
```

and I have a certain number of threads:

```
#define MAXTHREADS      32
TileTracer* worker[MAXTHREADS];
```

the number of working threads is set in the following initialization code, where the threads are also started:

```
void Renderer::Init(){
    accumulator = (vec3*)MALLOC64(sizeof(vec3)* SCRWIDTH * SCRHEIGHT);
    memset(accumulator, 0, SCRWIDTH * SCRHEIGHT * sizeof(vec3));
    SYSTEM_INFO systeminfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&systeminfo);
    int cores = systeminfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
    workerCount = MIN(MAXTHREADS, cores);
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
    {
        goSignal[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
        doneSignal[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    }
    // create and start worker threads
    for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
    {
         worker[i] = new TileTracer();
         worker[i]->init(accumulator, i);
         worker[i]->start(); //start the thread
    }
    samples = 0;
}
```

the init() method for my thread is simply defined in my header as the following:

```
void init(vec3* target, int idx) { accumulator = target, threadIdx = idx; }
```

while the start() is:

```
void Thread::start() 
{
     DWORD tid = 0; 
     m_hThread = (unsigned long*)CreateThread( NULL, 0,    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)sthread_proc, (Thread*)this, 0, &tid );
     setPriority( Thread::P_NORMAL );
 }
```

somehow (I don't get exactly where), each thread calls the following main method which is meant to define the color of a pixel (you don't have to understand it all):

```
vec3 TileTracer::Sample(vec3 O, vec3 D, int depth){
  vec3 color(0, 0, 0);
  // trace path extension ray
  float t = 1000.0f, u, v;
  Triangle* tri = 0;
  Scene::mbvh->pool4[0].TraceEmbree(O, D, t, u, v, tri, false);
  totalRays++;
  // handle intersection, if any
  if (tri)
  {
    // determine material color at intersection point
    Material* mat = Scene::matList[tri->material];
    Texture* tex = mat->GetTexture();
    vec3 diffuse;
    if (tex)
    {
        ...
    }
    else diffuse = mat->GetColor();
    vec3 I = O + t * D; //we get exactly to the intersection point on the object

    //we need to store the info of each bounce of the basePath for the offsetPaths
    basePath baseInfo = { O, D, I, tri };
    basePathHits.push_back(baseInfo);

    vec3 L = vec3(-1 + Rand(2.0f), 20, 9 + Rand(2.0f)) - I; //(-1,20,9) is Hard-code of the light position, and I add Rand(2.0f) on X and Z axis
    //so that I have an area light instead of a point light
    float dist = length(L) * 0.99f; //if I cast a ray towards the light source I don't want to hit the source point or the light source
    //otherwise it counts as a shadow even if there is not. So I make the ray a bit shorter by multiplying it for 0.99
    L = normalize(L);
    float ndotl = dot(tri->N, L);
    if (ndotl > 0)
    {
        Triangle* tri = 0;
        totalRays++;
        Scene::mbvh->pool4[0].TraceEmbree(I + L * EPSILON, L, dist, u, v, tri, true);//it just calculates the distance by throwing a ray
        //I am just interested in understanding if I hit something or not
        //if I don't hit anything I calculate the light transport (diffuse * ndotL * lightBrightness * 1/dist^2
        if (!tri) color += diffuse * ndotl * vec3(1000.0f, 1000.0f, 850.0f) * (1.0f / (dist * dist));
    }
    // continue random walk since it is a path tracer (we do it only if we have less than 20 bounces)
    if (depth < 20)
    {
        // russian roulette
        float Psurvival = CLAMP((diffuse.r + diffuse.g + diffuse.b) * 0.33333f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
        if (Rand(1.0f) < Psurvival)
        {
            vec3 R = DiffuseReflectionCosineWeighted(tri->N);//there is weight
            color += diffuse * Sample(I + R * EPSILON, R, depth + 1) * (1.0f / Psurvival);
        }
    }
  }
  return color;
}
```

Now, you don't have to understand the whole code for sure because my question is the following: if you notice, in the last method there are the 2 following code lines:

```
basePath baseInfo = { O, D, I, tri };
basePathHits.push_back(baseInfo);
```

I just create a simple struct "basePath" defined as follows:

```
struct basePath
{
    vec3 O, D, hit;
    Triangle* tri;
};
```

and I store it in a vector of struct defined at the beginning of my code:

```
vector<basePath> basePathHits;
```

The problem is that this seems bringing an exception. Indeed if I try to store these information, that I need later in my code, the program crashes giving me the exception:

Unhandled exception at 0x0FD4FAC1 (msvcr120d.dll) in Template.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x3F4C1BC1.

Some other times, without changing anything, the error is different and it's the following one:

[image]

While, without storing those info, everything works perfectly. Likewise, if I set the number of cores to 1, everything works. So, how come multithreading doesn't allow me to do it? Do not hesitate to ask further info if these are not enough.

Comment: Did you try to press "Retry" and go into the debugger? Where *in your code* does the crash happens? Have you checked the values of all involved variables?

Comment: Is `basePathHits` shared between all threads, or does each thread have its own version of it? If it's shared, are you synchronising access to it before attempting `push_back` on it (it doesn't look like you are)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the following change to your code:

```
//we need to store the info of each bounce of the basePath for the offsetPaths
basePath baseInfo = { O, D, I, tri }; 
static std::mutex myMutex;
myMutex.lock();
basePathHits.push_back(baseInfo);
myMutex.unlock();
```

If that removes the exceptions then the problem is unsychronised access to `basePathHits` (i.e. multiple threads calling `push_back` simultaneously). You need to think carefully about what the best solution to this will be, to minimise the impact of synchronisation on performance.

Comment: It doesn't solve the exception unfortunately.. I get what you mean by using a mutex and since this is my first time dealing with multithreading I didn't think about this problem.. but unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Referring back to your original post, "*While, without storing those info, everything works perfectly*" - by this, do you mean that if you remove the `push_back` line, you no longer see these exceptions?

Comment: Everything seems to be pointing to my original diagnosis, so I can't figure out why the `mutex` doesn't solve the problem... Is there any other part of your code that could modify `basePathHits`?

Comment: no there is not, already looked for that.. that's the only part where I modify basePathHits.. I am trying to come up with another solution: what about if instead of having basePathHits as global variable, I make it local so that each thread has its own basePathHits? it should be working, right? and how to do it? declaring that variable inside that specific method used by each thread should be enough?

Comment: I would make `basePathHits` a member variable of your `TileTracer` class, so each thread then writes into its own version of it.

Comment: that's what I did and it works indeed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Possible I did'nt see it, but there is no protection for the target - no mutex or atomic. And as far as I know std::vector needs this for multithreading.